# What songs can I stay in Overdrive for 60 seconds for?

Tags: achievements, rock-band-4

For the `Overflowing Overdrive` trophy in Rock Band 4, I have to remain in Overdrive for 60 seconds. I play solo guitar on expert and I'm wondering if it's possible to get this trophy by myself or if I'd need other players. If I can do this on my own, what songs that **came with the game** can I get this trophy with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only song present in the basic game that allows you to get that achievement by yourself seems to be **Dead Black (Heart of Ice)**.

According to [True achievements](https://www.trueachievements.com/a206578/overflowing-overdrive-achievement):

> You can get this achievement by yourself with an on-disc song: *Dead Black (Heart of Ice)*.
>   Toward the end of the song, the speed of the chart slows way down and overdrive drains way more slowly.

Also from [Xbox achievements](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/rock-band-4/achievement/106843-Overflowing-Overdrive.html):

> I can confirm what firedrake said, towards the end of *Dead Black (Heart of Ice)* when the song slows down a little you can deploy a full overdrive bar and hit some pretty easy overdrive sections to get the achievement

Other songs **not present on the basic game** are:

- "The Kill" by 30 Seconds to Mars, a DLC song
- "Slice of Your Pie" by Mötley Crue, a DLC song
- "Dani California" by Red Hot Chili Peppers, exported from the first Rock Band